# Inserting data into cell in different sheet (Excel & VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a fully working code that does various fascinating things. One of the things it does is validating some stuff based on an admin table on the same sheet.

This admin table is to be moved to another sheet ("admin" sheet).

When I try to alter my code to do this at the other sheet, it gives me an error.

Example code when admin table is on the same sheet:

```
If LastRow = 12 Then
    Sheets("Project Name & Series").Range("U12").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIFS(TEPSD!A:A,F12,TEPSD!C:C,G12,TEPSD!E:E,H12)>=1,TRUE,FALSE)"
Else
Sheets("Project Name & Series").Range("U12").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIFS(TEPSD!A:A,F12,TEPSD!C:C,G12,TEPSD!E:E,H12)>=1,TRUE,FALSE)"
Sheets("Project Name & Series").Range("U12").AutoFill Destination:=Range("U12:U" & LastRow)
End If
```

Example of code adapted to do the same on another sheet:

```
If LastRow = 12 Then
    Sheets("Admin").Range("C12").Forumla = "=IF(COUNTIFS(TEPSD!A:A,'Project Name & Series'!F12,TEPSD!C:C,'Project Name & Series'G12,TEPSD!E:E,'Project Name & Series'H12)>=1,TRUE,FALSE)"
Else
Sheets("Admin").Range("C12").Forumla = "=IF(COUNTIFS(TEPSD!A:A,'Project Name & Series'!F12,TEPSD!C:C,'Project Name & Series'G12,TEPSD!E:E,'Project Name & Series'H12)>=1,TRUE,FALSE)"
Sheets("Admin").Range("C12").AutoFill Destination:=("C12:C" & LastRow)
End If
```

VBA does not like it. I think because the "admin" sheet is not activated?

What is the easiest way to alter my code to do this, without having to re-write most of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'Project Name & Series'G12` should be `'Project Name & Series'!G12`

`'Project Name & Series'H12` should be `'Project Name & Series'!H12`

`Forumla` is spelled `Formula`

```
with workSheets("Admin")
    If LastRow = 12 Then
        .Range("C12").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIFS(TEPSD!A:A, 'Project Name & Series'!F12, TEPSD!C:C, 'Project Name & Series'!G12, TEPSD!E:E, 'Project Name & Series'!H12)>=1, TRUE, FALSE)"
    Else
        .Range("C12:C" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(COUNTIFS(TEPSD!A:A, 'Project Name & Series'!F12, TEPSD!C:C, 'Project Name & Series'!G12, TEPSD!E:E, 'Project Name & Series'!H12)>=1, TRUE, FALSE)"
    End If
end with
```

Comment: Sorry - what is this telling me?

Comment: You are missing `!` in two places.

Comment: What does "with" do?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement

Comment: I notice you do not do the ".AutoFill Destination:=("C12:C" & LastRow)" - is that deliberate?

Comment: Why write the formula once then autofill when you can just write it all at once?

Comment: I tried to use your solution, it is giving me an error. I think because I have not declared workSheets. What do I declare it as?

Comment: You don't. Worksheets is just a more definitive way of stating Sheets. Apparently you also misspelled Formula in two places.

Comment: I am not having a good day at all. Thank you so much for spotting these silly errors.